# Find possible values of a and b with derivates.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is:
Given that $y = ax^2 + bx$ and
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 4(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 - 32y$

Find possible values for constants a and b.

I worked out the first derivative to be 2ax +b and the second to be 2a. I'm just completely lost on where to go next apart from subbing in the derivatives.

Any help appreciated. :)

Comment: Is it bx or bc ?

Comment: Why does $\frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2}$ appear twice? Is it a typo? Should the second one be $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry apologies

Comment: what is the right equation now?

Answer (score 0):

So you have $$(2 a)^2 = 4 ( 2 a x+b)^2 - 32 (a x^2 + b x)$$

that needs to be solved for *all* values of $x$?

You can re-arrange the terms to get

$$ (16 a (a-2)) x^2 + (16 b (a-2)) x + (2 (2 b^2-a)) = 0 $$

which is solved for all $x$ with $$\begin{align} 16 a (a-2) & = 0 \\ 16 b (a-2) & = 0 \\ 2 b^2-a &= 0 \end{align}$$

From the last equation you have $a=2 b^2$ which can be substituted above for $64 b^2 (b^2-1)=0$ and $32 b (b^2-1)=0$. Ignoring the trivial $a=0$ and $b=0$ solution you have

$$\begin{align} a & = 2 \\ b & = 1 \\ &\boxed{y=2 x^2+x} \end{align} $$